# how to check if object in array exist? [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays

I receive a response from API in form of array object, but sometimes i receive different data in form of object data

for example :

```
//first response
$response->getBody();
//second response
$response->getMessage();
```

so if i call one of the response above that doesnt have the object , it's gonna have an error, what i've done so far is like this:

```
if(empty($response->getBody())){
   //do something
}
```

in conclusion i want to detect if the array of object has the object i want to call or use

Comment: without code, I am not sure. If it is an array, you can use if(isset($array['key']) . As an object, things are slightly different. You'll have to elaborate

Comment: do this: 
if (empty((array) $response)) {   
    if (method_exists($response,'getBody')){
       // do something
     }
}

Answer (score 0):

use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.method-exists.php) to check if the method of a class exits.

```
<?php 
  $directory = new Directory('.');
  var_dump(method_exists($directory,'read'));
?>
```

or use [is_callable()](http://php.net/manual/zh/function.is-callable.php)

```
class someClass {

   function someMethod()    {   }

 }

 $anObject = new someClass();

 $methodVariable = array($anObject, 'someMethod');

 var_dump(is_callable($methodVariable, true, $callable_name));  // 
 bool(true)

 echo $callable_name, "\n";  //  someClass::someMethod
```